# Recover Bitcoin Wallet info

Tags: blockchain, wallet-recovery

I sent some (worth around 1000usd) bitcoins to one of my wallets and doesn't remember which wallet it was. Now I'm checking wallet and seeing balance is still there. Can somebody tell me how do I see wallet information using wallet address (3CGphwQHf5QvK6dMrLcLQvQNCuBsc85T5k) or wallet name(1fac700f695d9d63).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot determine the software used to create an address wallet, and this is by design. Anything else would be a serious security flaw: everyone you transact with would be given information about how you store your bitcoin.

> wallet name(1fac700f695d9d63)

I assume this comes from an explorer site like OXT. If so, then it is simply an index created by their system to group transactions according to certain heuristics, it does not provide any info about the wallet software used in the first place.

I hope you are able to locate your coins, but the information you’ve provided is not sufficient to do so. Best of luck.